# How to throw custom exception with custom error code on fly in django rest framework and override default fields in exception response

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I would like to know how can I throw custom exception in django rest framework, that contains custom error_code and custom message. I am not interested in **APIException()** since this function does not allow for setting error code on fly. Additionally, I would like to know how to change the **details** key json response of exception message.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I found the solution for all of my questions

#### api_exceptions.py

```
from rest_framework.views import exception_handler
from rest_framework.exceptions import APIException
```

#### custom_exception_handler

```
def custom_exception_handler(exc, context):

    response = exception_handler(exc, context)

    if response is not None:
        response.data['status_code'] = response.status_code

        #replace detail key with message key by delete detail key
        response.data['message'] = response.data['detail']
        del response.data['detail']

    return response
```

#### CustomApiException

```
class CustomApiException(APIException):

    #public fields
    detail = None
    status_code = None

    # create constructor
    def __init__(self, status_code, message):
        #override public fields
        CustomApiException.status_code = status_code
        CustomApiException.detail = message
```

#### settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'utilities.helpers.api_exceptions.custom_exception_handler',
}
```

#### your_view.py

```
raise CustomApiException(333, "My custom message")

#json response
{
  "status_code": 333,
  "message": "My custom message"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
from rest_framework import exceptions

class ServiceUnavailableError(exceptions.APIException):
    status_code = status.HTTP_503_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE
    default_detail = "Service unavailable."

# your views.py
raise ServiceUnavailableError("Override message.")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple function that return a dict:

```
def response_error_message(dic, message="An error occurred please try again later.", http_status=None):
    dic["status_code"] = http_status or status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
    dic["object"] = message
    dic["success"] = False
```

And the call in your view:

```
...

responsedic = {}
response_error_message(response_dic, message='Custom message', http_status=Custom_http_status)
return Response(response_dic)
```